# Symmetries of the flag variety

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, reductive-groups

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a finite dimensional simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb C$, and let $\mathcal B=G/B$ be the associated Flag variety.
Is it true that the obvious map
$$
\mathfrak g\to \Gamma (T\mathcal B)
$$
from $\mathfrak g$ to the Lie algebra of globally defined algebraic vector fields on $\mathcal B$ is an isomorphism?

*Remark:*
There are examples where the corresponding statement for $G/P$ is false.

Comment: I don't understand: isn't $\Gamma$ a module over $C^\infty(G/P)$? How could it be finite dimensional?

Comment: I meant $\Gamma$ to mean algebraic sections (equivalently holomorphic sections). I'll edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is true. In fact, the homogeneous spaces $G/P$ such that $\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \Gamma (T_{G/P})$ is *not* an isomorphism have been classified (see e.g. M. Demazure, Inventiones math. 39, 179-186 (1977)): they are the odd-dimensional projective spaces, the Grassmannian of linear subspaces of maximal dimension in a smooth odd-dimensional quadric, and the 5-dimensional quadric. None of them is of the form $G/B$ (in fact they all have $b_2=1$).

Comment: To save people some typing: https://eudml.org/doc/142464

Also, would you happen to know some English reference?

Comment: I would like to point out that even though Demazure's classification is correct as stated, its proof contains two mistakes. They have been pointed out and corrected in a little note (in german) available on my home page. The first mistake is minor and affects the group of type $G_2$  over fields of arbitrary  characteristic (so including the complex numbers).  The other mistake requires a major revision for non-simply laced groups in very bad characteristic (2 or 3, respectively).

Comment: @Friedrich Knop: Thanks for your comment, this is quite useful to know.